# How do I solve “AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'documents'” error?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on this last 3 days. i don't have any idea.. there are similar question but i didn't got my answer.

this is ERROR

> File ID: 1U4XUrAhMk1WFAKE_IDqmQcteYqmIWPMFEd Traceback (most recent

File is Created I want to USE this ID and Edit Docs in Drive

> call last):   File "main.py", line 61, in

> ```
> main()   File "main.py", line 53, in main
> ```

> ```
> service.documents() AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'documents'
> ```

My goal

1. create Docs in GOOGLE Drive
2. insert Table in it

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import sys
from gdoctableapppy import gdoctableapp

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
    serviceDoc = build("docs", "v1", credentials=creds)
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    # Create Google Docs file in folder

    file_metadata = {
        "name": sys.argv[1],
        "parents": ["Folder ID"],
    }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields="id").execute()
    print("File ID: %s" % file.get("id"))

    DOCUMENT_ID = file.get("id")

    requests = [{"insertTable": {"rows": 2, "columns": 2, "location": {"index": 1}}}]

    result = (
        service.documents()
        .batchUpdate(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={"requests": requests})
        .execute()
    )
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are encountering such error is because your `service` variable is for Drive API, it doesn't have a `documents()` method.

**Use `serviceDoc` instead:**

```
serviceDoc.documents()
.batchUpdate(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={"requests": requests})
.execute()
```

---

### In addition:

I noticed that when you create a Docs file `mimeType` is not part of your `file_metadata`. If you create files without a specific `mimeType`, your newly created file will be `application/octet-stream`. See [Create Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file?hl=en)

If you want to create a Google Docs using Drive API, please add a `"mimeType"='application/vnd.google-apps.document'` in your `file_metadata`

**Sample:**

```
file_metadata = {
    "name": sys.argv[1],
    "mimeType"='application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    "parents": ["Folder ID"]
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Google Workspace and Drive MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)